# Need help getting FFMPEG to pipe alternate STDIO

Tags: powershell, unicode, ffmpeg, console, pipe

Problem: I need to pipe ffmpeg stream to a variable using PowerShell. The code below "works" (95% of the time), the problem is some Unicode characters do not exist when printed to the console which results in a malformed image.

Question: Is there a way to pipe bytes, decimal values, or even binary values instead of Unicode to console from ffmpeg???

```
clear-host
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 


$ffmpeg = "C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
$input = "C:\Users\Jukari\Desktop\test\test1.mp4"
$output = "C:\Users\Jukari\Desktop\test\test1.bmp"
$screenshot = 3


[console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UnicodeEncoding
[string]$image = & cmd /u /c "chcp 65001 > NUL && $ffmpeg -i `"$input`" -hide_banner -loglevel error -ss $screenshot -vframes 1 -an -c:v bmp -f image2pipe - 2>&1" 2>&1 | Out-String -Stream
[console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding


$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($image)
$stream = new-object System.IO.MemoryStream(,$bytes)
$image_out = [system.drawing.Image]::FromStream($stream,1,1)


write-host $image_out.Height
write-host $image_out.Width

if(Test-Path -LiteralPath $output)
{
   Remove-Item $output
}
$image_out.Save($output)
$image_out.Dispose()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As aside: `$input` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input), so choose a different variable name for that

Comment: Why not let ffmpeg write to a temporary file and use `[system.drawing.Image]::FromFile()` ?

Comment: The goal is to reduce IO to the hard disk.... that's why I'm not using FromFile.... I know the script here writes a file, but the end goal is to not write a file....